# JupyterLab: Error in file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection Traceback:

Tags: r, jupyter

Im am running R on JupyterLab from localhost. Plotting was working perfectly few days earlier but now cant plot anything on JupyterLab.

Code:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(model, year)) + geom_col()
```

Error:

```
Error in file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection
Traceback:
```

R version:

```
platform       x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu 
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the GitHub page? There's an extensive thread on this issue:
https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/210